# Netcool Object Server api

Tags: java, tivoli

Running Netcool 7.3.1.  Looking for simple api to access Object Server Tables.  I've already done the run an SQL command from nco_sql, and scraped the output into a C# data table, but wondering if there was some type of api that I could use for either C# or Java to access table data?

Answer (score 2):

If you can use a more up-to-date version of Omnibus, you can use the built-in HTTP / REST API.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSHTQ_8.1.0/com.ibm.netcool_OMNIbus.doc_8.1.0/omnibus/wip/api/concept/omn_api_http_overview.html?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use sybase database adapter so far I have used below three ways to query netcool object server:

1. Free TDS - This is free sybase client.
2. Jconn3 - this is paid sybase client, but if you are using WebGUI/Impact, this driver comes with TIP.
3. nco_sql - here you may need to create a file with query and then pass it to nco_sql. This require extra effort to parse column wise information as output will be on console.

I prefer jconn3, simple and similar to jdbc driver, you only need this jar in classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own java program to connect to Objectserver by simply initiating

```
//Load Sybase Driver
Class.forName("com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver");
String url = "jdbc:sybase:Tds:" + host + ":" + port;
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
```

Execute Statements

```
Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet result = stat.executeQuery("Select count(*) from alerts.status");;`
```